# How to get information ( specially headset device name ) of bluetooth headset device in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am creating an app where I need to display the name of connected bluetooth headset . My headset is switched on and connected to android device . I am routing phone audio to headset , but I am unable to display the connected headset name .

I tried with " getName () " method , but it returns another paired bluetooth mobile device which is not currently connected and switched off .

Need suggestions so badly .

**UPDATE**

I used this code . But unfortunately it returns an android bluetooth device name which is not currently connected , where my headset is still connected and I am able to route phone audio

```
            bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)      getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);


        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Set<BluetoothDevice> getDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        String remoteDevice = null;


        for (BluetoothDevice getDevice : getDevices) {

            //stringBuilder.append(getDevice);


            remoteDevice = getDevice.toString();

        }


        blueToothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(remoteDevice);

    StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder1.append(blueToothDevice.getName());
```

Comment: Add your code. You might be missing something obvious.

Comment: updated the post with code

Comment: As you're iterating through the list of devices, you need to look for the device you are interested in -- if you assign `remoteDevice` over and over, only the last device in the list will be represented. Further, it's not trivial to see whether a paired device is currently connected; the only thing you can do is to try to connect and listen for connectivity state.

Comment: Actually I am quite new to android . As being newer to android developing I don't have clear idea about listening to bluetooth connectivity state . I think it could be done with broadcast receiver . But as far I know broadcast receiver receives an intent when some event occurred . 
But suppose my app is not started yet , though bluetooth headset is paired and connected . If I launch my app later my app could not receive the broadcast intent , coz at the launching time no pairing or connection was made , as a result not broadcast was sent . What should I do at this moment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem . Previously I got all bonded devices with  " getBondedDevices() " method from " BluetoothAdpter " class . But I fixed the problem by using "getConnectedDevices" method from the class  " BluetoothProfile ".

My new code is below, which only shows the connected bluetooth headset device name which only connected to HEADSET profile .

```
   bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)      getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);


    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

               bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, listener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

public final BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener listener = new  BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    @Override

    public void onServiceConnected(int i, final BluetoothProfile      bluetoothProfile) {



        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


       List<BluetoothDevice> b = bluetoothProfile.getConnectedDevices();




        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for(BluetoothDevice getConnectedDevice : b){

            stringBuilder.append(getConnectedDevice.getName());


        }


    txt.setText(stringBuilder); 


    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int i) {
        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        txt.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
};
```